# Regex to format names

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking to find a regex that can remove characters and replace them with either a space, or with a comma and a space.
The problem is it ends up having 3 spaces, when I just want one. And if I try doing ", " I get 3 commas.

An example of how I want the output to be:

> FirstName LastName, FirstName Lastname

```js
var str = "&q=FirstNameLastName&q=FirstName2LastName2"
var newStr = str.replace(/[&q=]/g, ' ');

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: Why do you have `[]` around `&q=`? Do you understand what square brackets mean in a regexp?

Comment: How do you know where the first name ends and the second name begins? Will there *always* be casing in the format `FirstLast`? What if the user has a middle name?

Comment: Names are not always how you think they might be.  Mine has a hyphen in it.  See also: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

Comment: No casing in the string, but the first name last name will always start/end at a '&q='

Comment: I think the first step in your problem would be separating out what identifies a first name and what identifies a last name in your specific configuration. Spaces, hyphens, apostrophes and casing all need to be taken into consideration.

Comment: @ObsidianAge What does that have to do with replacing the `&q=` separators?

Comment: @Barmar -  While `&q` is one part of the question, there is also a separation between names to consider. The desired output is `FirstName LastName`. That's (likely) impossible to determine given an input of `&q=FirstNameLastName&q=...`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge OK. I'm just answering the part about "remove characters and replace them with a space", not the unstated problem of inserting spaces in the middle of the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the square brackets. `[&q=]` matches any single character that's either `&`, `q`, or `=`, and then you replace each of them with a space, so you get 3 spaces. This will also replace `q` characters in the names.

Just write the string that you want to replace by itself.

```js
var str = "&q=FirstNameLastName&q=FirstName2LastName2"
var newStr = str.replace(/&q=/g, ' ');

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: Wow I'm so dumb, this worked, and then all I did to remove the comma from the beginning was do a .slice(2) Thanks!